# JSON to DOM or innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, json, dom, innerhtml

I have this code:

```
try {
    var _o, _l, i, _d = new Array(), _c;
    _o = JSON.Parse( Request.Response );
    for ( i = 0, _l = _o.length; i < _l; i++ ) {
        _d[ i ] = document.createElement('div');
        _c = document.getElementById('comentsContainer');
        _c.removeChild( _c.firstChild );
        _d[ i ].className = 'comment-user';
        _c.appendChild( _d [i] );
    }
}
catch ( w ) {
    console.log( w );
}
```

The question is, is it better this way or should I use innerHTML ?

ADD: the object to parse :

```
"comments" : [
  { "user" : "foo", "comment" : "foo", "date" : "foo/foo/bar", "id_comment" : "bar" },
  { /* the same as above x10 */ }
]
```

Note that I want to parse each object from each array to a DOM element

Comment: I believe `innerHTML` is mostly the faster option, not to mention it requires a lot less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a structural representation of the data here (rather than raw HTML to parse), I'd say that your approach (using DOM manipulation methods) makes more sense than using an approach built around `.innerHTML`. In some cases, `.innerHTML` has shown to be a performance win, but I'm not sure that's a case on modern browsers with decent JavaScript engines. Furthermore, a lot of the gain you might get from dropping a blob of HTML into the `innerHTML` property is that you have to build that HTML from your `JSON` representation anyway, which will also take time. Since you have to process the `JSON` object, using the DOM manipulation methods is a sensible design approach.

Comment: So... what is your preference?

Comment: With the information provided in your question, I think the approach that you're taking is fine. A few unrelated comments: using more descriptive variable names will be helpful for you (and possibly others) down the road. Use `d = []` to create a new Array, rather than the outdated `new Array()` approach. Consider moving the DOM creation methods to create a comment block into a separate function with a descriptive name, to encourage code reuse. Of course, I don't know the whole context of the code snippets, so the comments might not be so useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend, I will do.
But this way not consume many processes?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `DOM` manipulation is a cleaner approach: `innerHTML` is a bit `spaghetti code`, where you mix the markup language with behavior (JavaScript), and you don't have a clear structure at the end. In addition, in most of the modern browsers `DOM API` are faster or equivalent to `innerHTML` in term of performance – unfortunately IE and Opera are not the case:

http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-or-dom/4

So, go for the `DOM APIs`, maybe you could clean and optimize a bit your code (e.g. you don't need to execute `getElementById` every loop to get the commentsContainer reference, you can have it outside; also not sure why you remove the first child every time you add a comment, seems to me that you could likely remove the comment you added previously, in that case can be optimized as well).

Comment: -1, It doesn't matter whether you use `.innerHTML` or `DOM` methods in the slightest bit, both methods require you to contain the markup data mixed with code. DOM code of course generally being much harder to maintain and write.

Comment: That's no true. Using DOM API you have a clear separation between DOM element and operation you perform on that element. Using `innerHTML` you have just *string*. `DOM APIs` gives to you a nicer and cleaner separation because you have objects for each HTML elements you're going to create/add/modify. Using `innerHTML` you have a string that can contains *everything*. That's why to me is spaghetti code.